# Determine remote client IP address for Java RMI call

Tags: java, networking, client-server, rmi

When I implement an RMI server (implement an interface that extends java.rmi.Remote) is there a way to get information about the current RMI request context, specifically the remote client's IP address?

```
public void myMethod() throws RemoteException {

    log.info("remote IP is "+ RMISomething.getSomething());

}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

See [java.rmi.server.RemoteServer#getClientHost](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/rmi/server/RemoteServer.html#getClientHost())

Comment: The link changed to: [RemoteServer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/rmi/server/RemoteServer.html#getClientHost%28%29)
 Your Server class must extend RemoteServer, UnicastRemoteObject or Activatable.

Comment: @chrise Your second sentence is incorrect. That's why UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject() is provided, and why RemoteServer.getClientHost() is static.

Comment: does it give port number too?

Comment: @Cybermonk As you would have seen when you looked it up via the link he kindly provided, it returns a `String` representation of the client host. I don't know why you're asking questions here in comments on an eleven year old answer when you could look it up for yourself. As you can see, it just wastes two months.

Comment: That link doesn't say anything about port. A "string rep" is ambiguous, could also have port in it "localhost:8080". If everyone can just look it up why do we need QA forums. Well to answer my question after creating a test class figured that port is not available.