# How can I get the Client IP of the java RMI programming?

Tags: java, client, ip, rmi

Can anyone explain how I can get the client IP of the Java RMI programming, including a sample of how to use it?

I have looked up the [Java API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/rmi/server/RemoteServer.html), but it is hard to understand.

I would like to print the client IP on server

Comment: what do you have that isn't working?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/590257/determine-remote-client-ip-address-for-java-rmi-call

Comment: What don't you understand? What's your question?

Comment: I added the coding,  it should be more helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only method in the `RemoteServer` class that you ever need to call is `getClientHost()`. That's the one that does what you asked about in your title.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution and what you guys meaning, thanks:

We need a try-catch to handle the getClientHost() function in the interface implementation of server.

**Here's the code:**

```
try{
    System.out.println(getClientHost()); // display message
}catch(Exception e){}
```